# How to populate Android GalleryView from database

Tags: android

I am writing an Android application where I need to populate GalleryView with images dynamically from a database. I will get images from  web and will store in SD card and store the absolute path of that images in  database.

When I query database, I need to populate Gallery View with images based on url which  I retrieve from local database. I am unable to do this. I am therefore seeking sample code to how to populate GalleryView in Android from database dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you have asked a question for GalleryView but still You can use this example to load Images inside Galleryview: [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

But, before using this example, you have to fetch the data from local database and then create your custom adapter by looking into the above example.